# Google Chrome hover toward tab causes Mac's menu bar at top of screen to come down

Tags: google-chrome

When I want to click a specific chrome tab in full screen, if I accidentally hover too high and hit the top of the screen the mac menu bar comes down.

Is there a way to disable to menu bar from coming down in this scenario? Or maybe a way to make it less sensitive.

Comment: System Settings > Control Centre, scroll to the bottom on right pane and try options for "Automatically hide and show the menu bar"  to accommodate your needs (choices are: "Always", "On Desktop Only", "In Full Screen Only", "Never")